# Парсинг avito через selenium + requests

Tags: python, selenium, requests

Дорогие разработчики!
Подскажите, как спарсить хоть что-то с одного объявления avito.ru
Перепробовал requests, selenium + selenium_stealth
Выводит ошибку:
ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101